# Execute job output

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a sql job with two steps, the first one would generate executable sql, is there a way to read a file or execute in step two the output from step one?

```
Step 1 = EXEC sp_help_revlogin
Step 2 = run output from step 1
```

Comment: is `EXEC sp_help_revlogin` the actual first step, or is this just an example?

Comment: Yes, I will most likely make it the first step but I need to automate this process so I need a way of executing the output from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the output from `sp_help_revlogin` is a SQL script. So if you modify `sp_help_revlogin` to return the script to your calling code via an output parameter (rather than just printing it), e.g.

```
Declare @output nvarchar(4000)
exec sp_help_revlogin @output out
```

Then you should just be able to execute the output via

```
EXEC sp_executesql @output
```

Comment: The formal parameter "@login_name" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Comment: Here's my actual sql statement.

Comment: The stored proc must declare that the parameter is for output,as well as the actual parameter requesting output.For example CREATE PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin
@login_name nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT 
AS...